# Is rule-based labelling available for qgis2web plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis2web, labeling

Does the qgis2web plugin support multi-attribute, rule-based labeling?

I'm trying to use the qgis2web plugin to export leaflet maps. The labeling on the map I want to export is rule-based. (eg  if x > 0 label with a || x). An export with this style produces a map with no labels.

[image: web map with no labels]

Here's what it looks like fully functional in QGIS: [image: multi-attribute, multi-line labels work in QGIS]

If I get rid of the rule-based label, but still use the multi-attibute, multi-line label (eg “X” || ‘\n’ “Y” ), I get a Python export error and no web map is produced.

So in trying to troubleshoot, I changed all the symbology and labels to the simplest terms, and the map successfully exports with labels (but is ugly and doesn't display the data I want). That leads me to believe it is the multi-attribute, rule-based labeling that is the problem.
[image: ugly map that works]

So in summary, does the qgis2web plugin support these types of labeling schema and I'm just doing it wrong, or is that a feature that's not available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, rule-bases styles are supported, but not rule-based labelling.

But you can modify the js code manually afterwards to use different labelling for each defined rendering style rules.

Multi-line labels are possible, but the syntax in QGIS is something like

`"city_label"  ||  '\n'  ||  "shape_area"`

and you might have to escape empty (NULL) values.

If your aim is to exclude polygons with NULL or zero values from rendering and labelling, think of setting a filter in the layer's properties before exporting to web.

Comment: This is correct - rule-based styles are supported, but rule-based labelling is not. Very happy to accept pull requests at https://www.github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/ if someone were prepared to develop the plugin to do this - it's certainly doable. But no, it's currently not supported.